# How to create a k sorted array using algorithm based on quicksort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quicksort

The question is, how to "**tweak**" the simple and basic version of the QuickSort algorithm, to have it produce a nearly-sorted array instead of a fully-sorted array, given a certain k?

Any help or direction will be appreciated!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_sorting, has a section on it, `partial_quicksort`, but figuring it out yourself first seems to be the point, no ? On SO you have to show what you have tried.

Comment: partial sorting, is to sort the smallest or largest k elements, for example-top 100 of the array. In my question i meant to a k sorted array where each element is at most k distance away from its target position in the sorted array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way - don't make recursive calls for slices with `right-left<k` (in case of recursive implementation) and don't put similar pieces onto stack in case of iterative implementation.

Comment: Thanks, complexity will be in the worst case - O(n*(n-k)), best case - O(n log(n\k)),   right?